# Xamarin Forms How To Compile NuGet Packages in Android .AAB Build

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I used Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 to create a cross-platform Xamarin Forms app which uses SQLite.  When I set the Android Package Format property to apk and test the app on Emulator or physical device everything works.  But when I changed this property to bundle and upload it to Play Store for testing I get and error that "Cannot create table with out columns, does (Models.TableName) contains public properties?"

Is there something I can do to get installed NuGet package to work in .aab archive as it does for .apk archives?

Comment: It might be the problem with linking... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker 
What is your Linker option in project's properties -> Android options? If it is `Sdk and User Assemblies`, try to change it to`Sdk Assemblies Only`. Or even `None`, just to check if this is the issue.